# Wake a sleeping trade convoy

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I accidentally put a trade convoy to sleep in Civilization Beyond Earth and cannot figure out how to waken.  I've searched the city screen and main screen and cannot find it.

Comment: Don't you usually have to click the unit and then select "Wake Unit"? (In Civ5, the icon was an alarm clock)

Answer (score 3):

The Trade Convoy should be at whichever city it was based at, though selecting it can sometimes be a little difficult if you have a fortified military unit in the same tile. I find zooming out can help with this:

[image: zoomed out view to show trade convoy icon]

You can then select the trade unit circle, which will bring up the unit's action menu. From there it's just the usual process of selecting the Establish Trade Route option or the Wake Up clock:

[image: trade vessel action menu]

If you've lost the trade unit completely, you can access it via the Military Overview menu, [as Dirty Beach describes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190222/wake-a-sleeping-trade-convoy/190399#190399).

Comment: As an addendum, you can click a tile multiple times to cycle through all units in that tile. I find it particularly helpful when issuing commands to aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

While Tim's answer is correct, there is certainly an easier way: open the military overview.
"Military overview" is a bit a misnomer in my mind. It's really just a list of your units.

You can open the military overview by clicking the '+' on the bottom bar, then selecting "Military Overview" from the options that appear, or by pressing the F3 key. Civilian units (Workers, Colonists, and Trade units) are at the bottom of the list. Find the unit you want, click it, and it will select it for actions. Close the overview, then issue commands to the selected unit.

Comment: Ah ha, I had looked there but apparently missed the Civilian Units option. That is indeed easier.